# Variable declaration not finding data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, temp-tables, user-defined-types

I want to store some data into a Table Type in SQL Server. In the code below, I define the structure of the table and declare it as a type. But later, the variable declared with that type cannot find it. The error is:

> Column, parameter, or variable #17: Cannot find data type ARTSRetailPriceModifier.

The code of the declarations and the assignment of the variable is:

```
CREATE TYPE ARTSRetailPriceModifier AS TABLE   
( 
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    RecID int,
    PromoId int,
    SNumber int,
    MCode VARCHAR(50),
    Amount DECIMAL(7,2),
    [Action] VARCHAR(20),
    NPrice DECIMAL(7,2),
    PPrice DECIMAL(7,2),
    RCode VARCHAR(1),
    PCondition VARCHAR(1)
);

DECLARE @PriceModifiers AS ARTSRetailPriceModifier

INSERT INTO @PriceModifiers (
    RecID,
    PromoId,
    SNumber,
    MdCode,
    Amount,
    [Action],
    NPrice,
    PPrice,
    RCode,
    PCondition
)

SELECT  d.RecID AS 'RecID'
    , 1 AS 'PromotionID'
    , d.SequenceNumber + 1 AS 'SequenceNumber'
    , 'PriceOverride'AS 'MethodCode'
    , ABS(d.RetailPrice - d.UnitListPrice) AS 'Amount'
    , 'Replace' AS 'Action'
    , d.UnitListPrice AS 'NewPrice'
    , d.RetailPrice AS 'PreviousPrice'
    , '1' AS 'ReasonCode'
, '1' AS 'PromoCondition' 
FROM #Items d
```

The table `#Items` is correctly filled.

Answer (score 0):

Add `GO` after `CREATE TYPE`.
See examples [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Possible explanation is that the type is not constructed or added to the system before transactions completes, yet we have to have a real type in the system when we are going to perform some actions with it.

Comment: Including `GO` does not compile in that context. FYI, i'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Yeah, it does not compile because you have a variable with name `PriceModifiers ` and not `Items `. And there is no column `SequenceNumber `, but `SNumber ` I believe,

Comment: That is not the point. Those are changed variable names. In my original code is fine. It just show a compile error for the `GO`: `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`.

Comment: Well, yeah, this is possible. But if you will try to add `GO` to code from your post, everything works without errors. Possibly, there are some conditions in your real code that case this error and I'm not aware of them.

Comment: In any case, I would suggest to separate the type creation and the actual code as you will face the error that the type is already existing. And separated code should work fine,